# Using any keyword is not filtering as required

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to filter lines from logs using any keyword. But the following works

```
match = [e.strip() for e in config.get('sky_messages', 'matches').split(',')]
with open(SOURCE_FILE+FILE_NAME, "r") as f:
for line in f:
    if any(word in line for word in match):
        pass
    else:
        print (line)
```

but this is what I wanted [only list the lines which do not contain any string in word ] and it's not working as expected. What mistake I am doing here?

```
match = [e.strip() for e in config.get('sky_messages', 'matches').split(',')]
with open(SOURCE_FILE+FILE_NAME, "r") as f:
for line in f:
    if any(word not in line for word in match):
        print (line)
```

Comment: Please share a minimum reproductive example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a logic problem. You're not getting the line if **any** of the words in `match` **are not** in `line`, the logic should be if **all** of the words in `match` **are not** in `line`.

So try changing this line:

```
    if any(word not in line for word in match):
```

To:

```
    if all(word not in line for word in match):
```